# HTML character entities replaced with characters in a JSP page

Tags: jsp, tomcat, web-applications, html-entities, html-escape-characters

I have the following `context-param` element in a Tomcat Webapp `web.xml` file:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>S_ALL_RIGHT_RESERVED</param-name>
  <param-value>Tous droits r&#233;serv&#233;s</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have the following code in a JSP:

```
<div>
  Without cout: ${initParam['S_ALL_RIGHT_RESERVED']}
  <br />
  With cout: <c:out value="${initParam['S_ALL_RIGHT_RESERVED']}"></c:out>
</div>
```

If I look at the source of the page, below is what I get:

```
<div>
  Without cout: Tous droits réservés
  <br />
  With cout: Tous droits réservés
</div>
```

What I would like to get instead is:

```
<div>
  Without cout: Tous droits r&#233;serv&#233;s
  <br />
  With cout: Tous droits r&#233;serv&#233;s
</div>
```

Can you tell what's wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.xml, try this:

```
<param-value><![CDATA[Tous droits r&#233;serv&#233;s]]></param-value>
```

Comment: Hi. If I try this, I get an error in Eclipse "XML document structures must start and end within the same entity."

Comment: Ok. Sorry, it works. I guess Tomcat needed a little time to swallow it. Thank you :)